# Implement fixedlabel in memoir

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir

I would like to implement a command called `\newfixedlabel` in analogy of memoirs
`\newfixedcaption` in such a way that:

```
\begin{myfloat}
\caption{...}
\label{myfloat:a}
...
\end{myfloat}
```

Yields the same result with `cleveref` (or any other package) than:

```
\myfloatfixedcaption{...}% setup via memoirs \newfixedcaption
\label{myfloat:a}
...
```

The reasoning behind this macro is that I can always change a float to
a nonfloat at any stage of the (document) writing process without losing
the label and caption facilities of a float.

A complete example may look like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cftonlycaption}[2][]%
{\begingroup
   \let\@makecaption\@gobbletwo
   \ifstrempty{#1}%
     {\caption{#2}}%
     {\caption[#1]{#2}}
 \endgroup}
\makeatother

\newfloat[chapter]{myfloat}{lmf}{My Float}
\newfixedcaption[\cftonlycaption]{\myfloatfixedcaption}{myfloat}

\crefname{myfloat}{My Float}{My Floats}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\begin{myfloat}
\caption{A}% or \myfloatfixedcaption{A}
\label{keya}
\end{myfloat}
\section{B}
\myfloatfixedcaption{B}
\label{keyb}
\cref{keya}
\cref{keyb}
\end{document}
```

For some reason the `\label{keyb}` command points
to section B instead of My Float.

Ps. I know about setting up cleveref with `\crefname`, the problem lies in creating the `\newfixedlabel` macro. I tried the same trick as memoir uses
to mimic a float environment by defining \@captype but to no avail.

Comment: You should post a complete working example to help people help you. Just a quick question, I assume that if you just use `\label`, it links back to the last section?

Comment: @T.Verron indeed thats the current problem. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @T.Verron MWE added

Comment: Just FYI, the MWE is missing `etoolbox`.

Comment: Sorry but what should it point to? Is it that it should point to the fixed caption thing? I'm just not familiar with the concept this is analogous to....

Comment: @PaulGessler. Indeed I have corrected the MWE.

Comment: @cfr It should point to the newfixedcaption.

Answer (score 1):

When using `\caption` inside a group, certain updates don't survive beyond that. In particular, `\caption` updates `\cref@currentlabel` which is necessary for [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) in order to detect the appropriate reference type.

You can update your `\cftonlycaption` to specifically reference the `myfloat` type using the following:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cftonlycaption}[2][]%
{\begingroup
   \let\@makecaption\@gobbletwo
   \ifstrempty{#1}%
     {\caption{#2}}%
     {\caption[#1]{#2}}
 \endgroup
 \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
      \expandafter\cref@override@label@type%
        \cref@currentlabel\@nil{myfloat}}}
\makeatother
```

The ending `\cref@currentlabel` update *outside* the group will store the current reference type as `myfloat`.

Alternatively, if this seems too rigid, you can always override the reference type locally using

```
\label[myfloat]{keyb}
```

Below is a minimal example using the former approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cftonlycaption}[2][]%
{\begingroup
   \let\@makecaption\@gobbletwo
   \ifstrempty{#1}%
     {\caption{#2}}%
     {\caption[#1]{#2}}
 \endgroup
 \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
      \expandafter\cref@override@label@type%
        \cref@currentlabel\@nil{myfloat}}}
\makeatother

\newfloat[chapter]{myfloat}{lmf}{My Float}
\newfixedcaption[\cftonlycaption]{\myfloatfixedcaption}{myfloat}

\crefname{myfloat}{My Float}{My Floats}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\begin{myfloat}
\caption{A}% or \myfloatfixedcaption{A}
\label{keya}
\end{myfloat}
\section{B}
\myfloatfixedcaption{B}
\label{keyb}% or \label[myfloat]{keyb}
\cref{keya}
\cref{keyb}
\end{document}
```

Note that voiding `\@makecaption` (via `\let\@makecaption\@gobbletwo`) causes [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to miss the appropriate jumping location.